# What types of Written Design Documents are used in DDD projects?

Tags: domain-driven-design

1.Which of the following types of *written design documents* do we normally use on DDD projects:

a. *Requirements specifications* document

b. Document explaining the the *meaning* of *core elements*

c. Document giving the *bird's eye view* of an *application structure*

d. Document explaining the *meaning behind the terms* used by Ubiquitous language

e. Document listing the *vocabulary* of *Ubiquitous language*

f. Informal UML diagrams

anything else?

2.Which *document types*  should be created as *standalone documents* and which should be combined within a single document ( example: document containing diagrams surrounded by text )?

3.And what are *Requirements specifications*? A list of *use cases*, a list of *tasks* program is able to perform or *combination* of both?

thanks

Comment: There are also reference scenarios and user stories - http://www.slideshare.net/skillsmatter/ddd-in-agile

Comment: @eulerfx What is a reference scenario? I googled it and couldn't find any information. Can you help with my other questions also (no hard feelings if you won't ;))

Comment: Watch this - http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/design-architecture/paulrayner-domain-scenarios

Comment: I've posted a comprehensive reply on my blog at http://thepaulrayner.com/blog/2013/05/07/succeeding-with-ddd-documentation/. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

- A statement of the purpose of your application in 25 words or less
- A representation of your model in both code and uml
- A list of features corresponding to the current or desired model
- A list of constraints (business rules) on the model
- Where applicable, a sequence diagram for each feature
- A statement of non-functional requirements
- An architectural overview for team members (including model boundaries and contexts)
- Team instructions and procedures

Note: use cases or user stories can inform your list of features.  However, I recommend that a feature be the unit of work.

I recommend that the initial model be created (discovered) in a modeling workshop attended by both domain experts (business) and developers. It must be led by someone proficient in domain modeling.

Business rules are constraints on the model of two types: Property and Collaboration.  By way of example, business rules prevent an elevator from moving with the doors open, a perishable item being placed in a non-refrigerated bin, or a cancelled purchase being shipped.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Event Storming](http://eventstorming.com) might be a good solution. A photo of the workshop should be enough. If not you can use the same artifacts into a digital document.